# How do I return multiple results in a SQL subquery?

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I have a query below and would like to know if it is possible to get more than 1 result. I would like to get the 4 most recent entries.

Thanks!

```
select c.email,c.text,m.alertDataID  
from client_users as c, monitor_alerts as a, monitor_alerts_data as m
where c.id=a.userID and a.alertID=m.alertID and 
m.alertDataID = (SELECT alertDataID FROM monitor_alerts_data ORDER BY alertDataID DESC LIMIT 1) 
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IN` instead of `=`:

```
 ... and m.alertDataID IN (SELECT alertDataID FROM ...)
```

Also don't limit your subquery to `LIMIT 1`. You'll need `LIMIT 4` in the sub-query.

Comment: My version of mysql doesn't support limit & in/all/any/some subquery... Any other ideas?

Comment: Don't use a LIMIT at all in the subquery then, simply limit your outer result set. PS. What version of MySQL are you using?